# Do these FOL formula both represent "You can fool some of the people all of the time"?

Tags: logic, symbolic-ai

> You can fool some of the people all of the time.

This can be represented in FOL as follows

$$\exists x \; \forall t  \; (\text{person}(x) \land \text{time}(t)) \Rightarrow \text{can-fool}(x,t) \tag{1}\label{1}$$

Is $\exists x \; \forall t \; \text{can-fool}(\text{person}(x), \text{time}(t))$ equivalent to (\ref{1}) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) can be paraphrased as "There exists an *x*, and for any *t* if *x* is a person and *t* is a time, then *x* can be fooled at time *t*" (I would use *fool-able* instead of *can-fool*, as it is closer to the intended meaning).

(2) would be "There exists an *x*, and for any *t*, you can fool *x* is a person and *t* is a time."

They are not equivalent: *person(x)*  and *time(t)* are boolean predicates, which return a truth value: they are true if *x* is a person, and *t* is a time, respectively. So in (1) they act as a constraint on the values that *x* and *t* can take. If *x* was a saucepan, then *person(x)* would be false, and thus you wouldn't be able to claim that you can fool a saucepan.

So *can-fool* takes two arguments: one for which *person* is true, and one for which *time* is true. But in (2), the arguments are actually the boolean truth values: if *x* was "Falstaff" and *t* was "yesterday", then in (1) the premise would be true, as *person("Falstaff")* and *time("yesterday")* are true, and so you conclude *can-fool("Falstaff", "yesterday")*.

In (2) that becomes *can-fool(person("Falstaff"), time("yesterday"))*, which evaluates to *can-fool(true, true)*, and that won't work.